# retrieve only numbers from a file with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have file.txt with the following content:

```
    34455
    55676
66677
6888868,
6688886
n\
n\
```

How can I retrieve only the digits between 5 and 7 number, without any characters or blanks? the expected output is this:

```
34455
55676
66677
6888868
6688886
```

Comment: You're trying to delete where there is an empty line, or you're trying to remove all non-digits from the file (there are other characters in the file, and you want the output to be one long liner of numbers)? Perhaps put a larger sample of original text and also how you'd want the output to be.

Comment: everything that is not digits

Comment: All you need, including samples of how, are in the built-in Powershell help files, and the plethora PowerShell text file management examples all over Superuser and the web. A quick web lookup, using your exact post title, would give you a very long list of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the file and get only digit match, using the Get-Content using the -replace switch using regex to get your data. What you are after is common string replacement.

```
# https://wisetut.com/only-numbers-in-regex-regular-expression/
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Scripts\MyNumbersFile.txt') -match '\d'
```

Read up on PS file management:

- [retrieve only numbers from a file with powershell](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27retrieve%20only%20numbers%20from%20a%20file%20with%20powershell%27&t=h_&ia=web)
- [Powershell and text files](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27Powershell%20and%20text%20files%27&t=h_&ia=web)

***Update - try this:***

```
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Scripts\MyNumbersFile.txt') -match '\d' -replace '\s*' -replace ','
```

***Update - other thoughts***

```
Clear-Host
('

    34455
    55676
66677
6888868,
6688886
n\
n\
' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header MyNumber) -match '\d'

# Results
<#
MyNumber
--------
34455   
55676   
66677   
6888868 
6688886 
#>

(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Scripts\MyNumbersFile.txt' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header MyNumber) -match '\d' 

# Results
<#
MyNumber
--------
34455   
55676   
66677   
6888868 
6688886 
#>
```

Further update as per your last comment and mine to you.
[Using .Net RegEx group match](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-6.0) and [using -Raw when using Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2)

```
# This... 
[RegEx]::Matches((Get-Content -Path 'D:\Scripts\MyNumbersFile.txt'), '\d{5,7}').Value

# Or this...
[RegEx]::Matches((Get-Content -Path 'D:\Scripts\MyNumbersFile.txt' -Raw), '\d{5,7}').Value
# The end results are the same either way
<#
34455
55676
66677
6888868
6688886
#>
```

Comment: but that goes through line by line?

Comment: Yes, it does, and based on your posted sample output, that's what you are showing you wanted. Are you saying, you want all these numbers on the same line with no spaces? Nothing prevents you from doing that. You just remove the CRLF; or are you saying you want each individual digit on its own line? Well, that means creating an array out of each line and processing from there.

Comment: not work for me

Comment: Couldn't it be done with select-string better?

Comment: -Replace, Select-String for what you are trying to do is the same thing. Both require a pattern (RegEx) to remove or grep what you want out of that string. Which you use is up to you. You are still cleaning up a list or CRLF formatted data, and each must be processed one line at a time, or you take the extra step of reading it all in Get-Content -Raw, and working with that. See my update for you, and note the additional specificity needed.

Comment: can you help me with this https://superuser.com/questions/1733921/how-to-escape-the-line-to-run-powershell/1734014?noredirect=1#comment2683676_1734014

Comment: ***'can you help me with this superuser.com/questions/1733921/… – 
ortiga'*** See my comment and sample for you in that post.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
(Get-Content -Path 'C:\Path\to your\file.txt')  -replace "\D","" -replace "^\d{1,3}$","" -replace "^\d{8,}","" -match "\S"
```